# Write a MAT file without using matlab headers and libraries

Tags: java, c++, matlab, mat-file

I have some data that I would like to save to a MAT file (version 4 or 5, or any version, for that matter). The catch: I wanted to do this without using matlab libraries, since this code will not necessary run in a machine with matlab. My program uses Java and C++, so any existing library in those languages that achieves this could help me out...

I did some research but did not find anything in Java/C++. However, I found that scipy on python achieves this with `mio4.py` or `mio5.py`. I thought about implementing this on java or C++, but it seems a bit out of my time schedule.

So the question is: is there any libraries in Java or C/C++ that permits saving MAT files without using Matlab libraries?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I take it that you have found a copy of The Mathwork's document 'MAT-file Format' and do not want to roll your own code until you've exhausted the possibility of SO helping you find an already-written library ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

C: [matio](http://sourceforge.net/projects/matio/)
Java: [jmatio](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmatio/)
(I'm really tempted to, so I will, tell you to learn to google)

But really, it's not that hard to write matfiles using `fwrite` if you don't need to handle some of the more complex stuff (nested structs, classes, functions, sparse matrix, etc).
See: http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/pdf_doc/matlab/matfile_format.pdf

Comment: I had a similar problem some time ago and ended up writing a set of functions as a drop-in replacement for the matlab API for writing .matfiles. Nothing fancy, but it does the basics (including structures ans nesting). It's up on github: http://github.com/EyNuel/matOut/wiki

Answer (score 5):

MAT files since version 7 are HDF5 based. I recall that they use some rather funny conventions, but you may be able to reverse engineer what you need. There are certainly HDF5 writing libraries for both Java and C++.

Along these lines, Matlab can read/write several standard formats, including HDF5. It may be easiest to write your data in "standard" HDF5 and read it into the desired data structure within Matlab.

Comment: +1 I thought I'd read that somewhere but can never find confirmation when I go looking.  You raise another possibility, OP could read/write HDF5 files which MATLAB can definitely handle whatever it's own implementation of MAT files might be.

Comment: HDF5 is row-major. Mat is column-major. The current `help` on hdf5write explains a little bit about why this can be a bad thing

Comment: @kts: yes, but the order in which Matlab writes to an HDF5 file can be switched.  I've never found this to be a problem in practice, though i have occasionally had to transpose a matrix in Matlab or a Fortran program.