# Can I load MATLAB mat file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, matlab

In Python I can use `scipy.io.loadmat` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html) to load/import MATLAB mat files,
Looks like `SciRuby` (http://sciruby.com/) does not have a similar facility.
Is there any other ruby library or any other way, to load/import mat files in Ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, SciRuby does have it now.

You'll need to get NMatrix from git instead of through RubyGems:

```
git clone git://github.com/SciRuby/nmatrix.git
cd nmatrix
rake repackage
gem install pkg/nmatrix*.gem
```

and then you can do:

```
m = NMatrix::IO::Matlab::load_mat 'filename.mat'
```

Hope this helps! It'll be in the gem as well once 0.0.2 gets released.

Comment: Remember to bundle install before repackaging

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer.

If you save in matlab in the 7.3 format it's actually hdf5 for which ruby libraries exist.

For the older format it should be possible to wrap one of the libraries from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700195/write-a-mat-file-without-using-matlab-headers-and-libraries).

Comment: If I am not much mistaken (at least in matlab) you can only store simple data types (I mean numbers like int, double ...) in HDF5 datasets. For me the whole point of a matlab mat file if its flexibility for complex data structures (`struct`) and its flexibly sizes. I think this solution won't work for my purposes. If I had a simple/manageable data structure I could have exported them to delimited text files and read them back.

Comment: That may be the case for the hdf5 commands(never used them). But the 7.3 matfile has the same functionality as the previous versions (although being slower at the moment). So it completely supports any data structure you can come up with.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you, you mean I should be able to save a mat file with the `-v7.3` switch and open it with a ruby HDF5 library? If this is what you meant, do you have a ruby gem/library in mind that I can use for this?